# JSON to Java POJO classes not able to extract all details

Tags: java, json, pojo

I am using jackson parser to parse json. I want to extract "props" from below JSON. Please suggest what changes are required in java POJO class to get "props" value. Below is the json and equivalent POJO classes.

JSON-

```
{
    "iActs": [
        {
            "iAct": "ref",
            "refConfigs": {
                "responseTypes": [
                    "COMPLETE",
                    "INCOMPLETE"
                ]
            },
            "sets": [
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "set": "APROFILE",
                    "attrs": [
                        {
                            "id": 1,
                            "attr": "APROFILE.FAN",
                            "configs": {
                                "iResp": true
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 2,
                            "attr": "APROFILE.BTC",
                            "configs": {
                                "iResp": true
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 3,
                            "attr": "APROFILE.HNAME",
                            "configs": {
                                "iResp": true
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 4,
                            "attr": "APROFILE.HDETAILS",
                            "props": [
                                "Delhi",
                                "Mumbai",
                                "Kolkata",
                                "Bangalore",
                                "Jalandhar"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

JAVA POJO-

IActs.java

```
public class IActs
{
    private RefConfigs refConfigs;

    private String iAct;

    private Sets[] sets;

    public RefConfigs getRefConfigs ()
    {
        return refConfigs;
    }

    public void setRefConfigs (RefConfigs refConfigs)
    {
        this.refConfigs = refConfigs;
    }

    public String getIAct ()
    {
        return iAct;
    }

    public void setIAct (String iAct)
    {
        this.iAct = iAct;
    }

    public Sets[] getSets ()
    {
        return sets;
    }

    public void setSets (Sets[] sets)
    {
        this.sets = sets;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [refConfigs = "+refConfigs+", iAct = "+iAct+", sets = "+sets+"]";
    }
}
```

Sets.java

```
public class Sets
{
    private String id;

    private Attrs[] attrs;

    private String set;

    public String getId ()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId (String id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Attrs[] getAttrs ()
    {
        return attrs;
    }

    public void setAttrs (Attrs[] attrs)
    {
        this.attrs = attrs;
    }

    public String getSet ()
    {
        return set;
    }

    public void setSet (String set)
    {
        this.set = set;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [id = "+id+", attrs = "+attrs+", set = "+set+"]";
    }
}
```

Attrs.java

```
public class Attrs
{
    private Configs configs;

    private String id;

    private String attr;

    public Configs getConfigs ()
    {
        return configs;
    }

    public void setConfigs (Configs configs)
    {
        this.configs = configs;
    }

    public String getId ()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId (String id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getAttr ()
    {
        return attr;
    }

    public void setAttr (String attr)
    {
        this.attr = attr;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [configs = "+configs+", id = "+id+", attr = "+attr+"]";
    }
}
```

Configs.java

```
public class Configs
{
    private String iResp;

    public String getIResp ()
    {
        return iResp;
    }

    public void setIResp (String iResp)
    {
        this.iResp = iResp;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [iResp = "+iResp+"]";
    }
}
```

RefConfigs.java

```
public class RefConfigs
{
    private String[] responseTypes;

    public String[] getResponseTypes ()
    {
        return responseTypes;
    }

    public void setResponseTypes (String[] responseTypes)
    {
        this.responseTypes = responseTypes;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [responseTypes = "+responseTypes+"]";
    }
}
```

I tried few ways but none are working. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your Set class should have a an Attrs object instance instead of an array Attrs []. You need to change your Attrs to have a collection of an object Attr (for example). In that object is were you should define the attributes: id, attr, configs and props. You also need to create a new Props object.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the following to your Attrs class:

```
private String [] props;
public String[] getProps() {
    return props;
}
public void setProps(String[] props) {
    this.props = props;
}
```